# SQLite replace string while inserting into table

Tags: sqlite, replace, sql-insert

I have a spreadsheet that contains a table in which a user can define a generic format for specific objects. For example, a small snippet of that spreadsheet can be seen below. Some cells within that table contain wildcards, such as [tag], [path], or [device shortcut].

[image: Small sample of spreadsheet]

I created a python script that loads the table from that spreadsheet into a SQLite table that I've called "alarm_definitions".

I've created another SQLite table that matches the schema of "alarm_definitions" using the below query.

```
CREATE TABLE discovered_alarms_for_objects AS
SELECT *
FROM alarm_definitions;
```

I want to insert into the discovered_alarms_for_objects table by joining several other tables together while at the same time, replacing the wildcards with data collected from the other tables. Can this be done? I've started to put my INSERT INTO discovered_alarms_for_objects query together (shown below), but am hung up with how to replace while inserting.

```
INSERT INTO discovered_alarms_for_objects(
    alarm_type,
    name,
    input_tag)
SELECT
    alarm_definitions.alarm_type,
    discovered_objects_with_alarms.id,
    discovered_objects_with_alarms.tag
FROM
    discovered_objects_with_alarms
    INNER JOIN objects_with_alarms ON objects_with_alarms.id = discovered_objects_with_alarms.object_with_alarm_id
    INNER JOIN alarms_for_objects ON alarms_for_objects.object_with_alarm_id = objects_with_alarms.id
    INNER JOIN alarm_definitions ON alarm_definitions.id = alarms_for_objects.alarm_definition_id;
```

Ultimately, for a given row in discovered_alarms_for_objects, I want all instances of [tag] to be replaced with the appropriate value from discovered_objects_with_alarms.tag. [path] would get replaced with plcs.path, and [device shortcut] would be replaced with plcs.device_shortcut. See below for a small sample of what I am hoping to achieve.

[image: Small sample of desired outcome]

Answer (score 0):

As a an example of using `replace` in an `INSERT SELECT` consider this simplification of what you have supplied where:-

- if the **name** has [tag], then it will be **replaced** with `[this was the tag]****REPLACED` i.e. using `replace(name,'[tag]','[this was the tag]')||'****REPLACED'`

The full demo code (SQL) being:-

```
/* Just in case cleanup */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS alarm_definitions;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS discovered_alarms_for_objects;
/* Columns based upon the spreadsheet */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS alarm_definitions (alarmtype TEXT, name TEXT, inputtag TEXT);
/* Add some data (first row of the spreadsheet) */
INSERT INTO alarm_definitions VALUES('Alm','[tag]_Alm','[path][device shortcut][tag].Alm');
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS discovered_alarms_for_objects AS SELECT * FROM alarm_definitions; /* changed from ...alarm.... to ....alarms.... PLURAL*/
/* show the resultant discoverered.... table */
SELECT * FROM discovered_alarms_for_objects;
/*<<<<<<<<<< Simplified INSERT SELECT with replace >>>>>>>>>>*/
INSERT INTO discovered_alarms_for_objects (
    alarmtype, /* changed from alarm_type */
    name,
    inputtag)
SELECT
    alarmtype, /* changed from alarm_type */
    replace(name,'[tag]','[this was the tag]')||'****REPLACED',
    inputtag
FROM
    /*
    discovered_objects_with_alarms
    INNER JOIN objects_with_alarms ON objects_with_alarms.id = discovered_objects_with_alarms.object_with_alarm_id
    INNER JOIN alarms_for_objects ON alarms_for_objects.object_with_alarm_id = objects_with_alarms.id
    INNER JOIN alarm_definitions ON alarm_definitions.id = alarms_for_objects.alarm_definition_id;
    */
    alarm_definitions; /* to simplify example */
/* Show result of the insert */
SELECT * FROM discovered_alarms_for_objects;

/* Cleanup demo environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS alarm_definitions;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS discovered_alarms_for_objects;
```

**Result**

- The **discovered_alarms_for_objects** when created based upon the **alarm_definitions** table *(if you want no data to be inserted then use a WHERE clause to select nothing)* :-

[image]

- The **discovered_alarms_for_objects** after the `INSERT .... SELECT ....` replacing [tag] in the **name** column:-

[image]

- i.e. the first row already existed
- the second row shows the inserted row with [tag] replaced. Obviously joins could added as required.

  - somehow I doubt that you want such a simplistic replacement in which case more complicated expressions could be utilised to suit (i.e. no clarity has been provided as to the actual requirements and hence the theoretical example).

Comment: I had intended on having [tag] be dynamically replaced with the appropriate value from the table discovered_objects_with_alarms.tag, so no, it isn't quite as simple as statically replacing "[tag]" with "[some other tag]". I'll update the question to reflect this requirement.

Comment: Actually, after looking over your answer a bit more, I realized that my replace statement could use the table.column reference directly. For example, using replace(alarm_definitions.name,'[tag]',discovered_objects_with_alarms.tag) did exactly what I wanted it to.

Comment: @kubiej21 that was roughly what the last bullet point was alluding to in general.